# DROP EVENT query will not fire from inside a routine

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm working on a password updater with a 2-hour update slot.
Passwords are stored in a `Users` table and I have another table `ChangeRequests` responsible for storing data required to process the password updating.

Once the request has been submitted via the website frontend, an email is created and a password reset record saved in the DB. This request also creates a scheduled event `PwdUpdateRq` to delete the said record 2 hours after creation.

Once the new password is submitted and verified, the frontend calls for a stored procedure `TidyPwdRq` containing 2 queries: **DELETE FROM `ChangeRequests`** and **DROP EVENT `PwdUpdateRq`**.

The problem is: DROP event doesn't seem to like it when the name of the event is being passed as a parameter into the procedure. Is there a way to bypass this?

For clarity, each new drop event is being assigned the ID of the corresponding `ChangeRequests` record and it does get destroyed after 2 hours regardless. Also, because the record holding the request data will be gone once the password has been updated, it's not a big issue at all if it can't be rid of then.

Following is the screenshot of the Edit Routine dialog: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CZN6.png)

Comment: Ckeck: `An event may not be created, altered, or dropped from within a stored program, if the event name is specified by means of a variable. An event also may not create, alter, or drop stored routines or triggers.`, see [Restrictions on Stored Programs :: Event Scheduler Restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-event-restrictions).

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MariaDB?

Comment: @wchiquito MariaDB 10.3.32-1040 - most up to date available on DSM

Answer (score 1):

Since the event name is variable, you have to use a prepared statement inside your procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE example_drop_event(IN event_name varchar(64))
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE concat("DROP EVENT IF EXISTS ", event_name);
END
```

**Update**: Added improvement from *Dan Black's* comment and use EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE (which is shorthand for prepare + execute + deallocate).

Comment: `DROP EVENT` is not supported by [Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) (currently) as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: In MariaDB (question has tag `mariadb`) all kind of commands are supported in prepared statements since version 10.6.2. See also https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-16708

Comment: `DROP EVENT` is not supported by [Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) (currently in MySQL) as mentioned in the documentation. In MariaDB (starting with 10.6.2) is supported, see [PREPARE Statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/prepare-statement/).

Comment: The [execute immediate](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/) MariaDB feature makes this quicker: `CREATE PROCEDURE example_drop_event(IN event_name varchar(64)) EXECUTE IMMEDIATE concat("DROP EVENT IF EXISTS ", event_name)`

Comment: @wchiquito thanks for the update on MariaDB prepared statements.

Comment: GeorgRichter, danblack
Many thanks for the solution. I will implement it once the update for MariaDB is released on DSM.